# Dynamic create table using input range with jquery

Tags: jquery, input, range

Anybody can explain me, why when I set my table using input range with 5 columns and 5 rows, and then, when I will change size rows, for example to 3 rows, and next all table will be empty, then I have to change value one more time, if my table was 3 rows. When rows are constants, and I set only columns using input range everything working.

http://jsfiddle.net/Efxba/

Comment: There is a reason why you cannot post fiddle links without including some code.

Comment: Because you cannot guarantee that it will be online for the lifetime of SO. Additionally a fiddle can contain more code. It's better to just post relevant code inside the question.

Comment: A link yo jsFiddle is fine and helpful but it must not be the only thing in the question. Show the code in your questions too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all add `value="5"` to each `input type="range"` to have default values.

Then in end of `$('#rows').changed` call function `$('#cols').changed();` to fill rows with columns when table rows count changed.

Finally add to `$(document).ready` function `$('#rows').changed();` call to update table when document is ready.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Efxba/2/)

HTML:

```
<input type="range" id="rows" name="rows" min="0" max="10" value="5" />
<input type="range" id="cols" name="cols" min="0" max="10" value="5" />
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var wartosc;
    var wartosc2;
    var i = 0;
    var j = 0;

    $('#rows').change(function() {
        $('table tr').remove();              
        //alert(document.body.innerHTML);
        var newVal = this.value;
        wartosc = newVal;
        $('#newValue').html(newVal);

        $("table ").each(function () {
            for (i = 0; i < wartosc; i++) {
                $(this).append('<tr>');                        
            }
        });
        $('#cols').change()
    });

    $('#cols').change(function() {
        $('table td').remove();
        var newVal = this.value;
        wartosc2 = newVal;
        $('#newValue2').html(newVal);
        $("table tr").each(function() {
            for (j = 0; j < wartosc2; j++) {
                $(this).append('<td>asdad</td>');
            }
        });
    });
    $('#content').append('<table border="1"></table>');
    var table = $('#content').children();
    $('#rows').change();
});
```